# How to add the Count Vectorizer to Simple RNN model?

Tags: keras, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, countvectorizer

For my `NLP` project I used `CountVectorizer` to Extract Features from a dataset using vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english') and all_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(data.Text)  and i also wrote a Simple RNN model using keras but I am not sure how to do the padding and the tokeniser step and get the data be trained on the model.

my code for RNN is:

```
model.add(keras.layers.recurrent.SimpleRNN(units = 1000, activation='relu',
use_bias=True))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1000, input_dim = 2000, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=500, input_dim=1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_dim=500,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

return model
```

can someone please give me some advice on this?

Thank you

Comment: will you show your rnn code?  did you create a pipeline

Comment: i didn't create  pipeline. I created a simple RNN with some dense layers.

Comment: please show the code

Comment: model.add(keras.layers.recurrent.SimpleRNN(units = 1000, activation='relu', use_bias=True)) model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1000, input_dim = 2000, activation='sigmoid')) model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=500, input_dim=1000, activation='relu')) model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_dim=500,activation='softmax')) model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add ensemble - you don't count vectorize, you use ensemble

https://github.com/dnishimoto/python-deep-learning/blob/master/UFO%20.ipynb

```
 docs=ufo_df["summary"] #text
 LABELS=['Egg', 'Cross','Sphere', 'Triangle','Disk','Oval','Rectangle','Teardrop']
 #LABELS=['Triangle']
 target=ufo_df[LABELS]
 #print([len(d) for d in docs])
 encoded_docs=[one_hot(d,vocab_size) for d in docs]
 #print([np.max(d) for d in encoded_docs])
 padded_docs = pad_sequences(encoded_docs,   maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

 #print([d for d in padded_docs])
 model=Sequential()
 model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 8,   input_length=max_length))
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
#model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

 model.fit(padded_docs, target, epochs=50, verbose=0)
```

Comment: thank you! I'll try that. Could you please explain why CountVectorizer would not work. I applied it on Classifiers such as SVM but I  am not sure how/ why I can't apply it on RNN and other deep learning methods.

Comment: one_hot does the vectorizing.  https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/one-hot-encoding-129ccc293cda    if you want to use count vector then try this approach: https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/keras-for-multi-label-text-classification-86d194311d0e

Comment: the code padding is required to match the input of the keras network.  you get the max size of words in the sentences then encode the sentence and pad the sentence documents.  this is the function of pad_sequences

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I managed to implement it using the link. the accuracy is only around 0.58 but I hope it will get better if i change the parameters. Thank you!

Comment: did you remove stop-words

Comment: i removed stop words but didn't add a maxabsscaler. I'll try that next. could you please clarify what you mean by pipeline. I looked it up as well but could not find any good explanations. Many thanks

Comment: no pipeline. try the maxabscaler transformation

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you